# count clustered values in csv

Tags: r, csv, count, gaps-and-islands

I have a csv file with rows containing a name followed by series of null values and clustered real values.

```
Robert,,,1:00-5:00,1:00-5:00,1:00-5:00,,,,,,2:00-4:00,2:00-4:00,2:00-4:00
John,,,1:00-5:00,1:00-5:00,,,,,,,,,,,,
Casey,,,1:00-5:00,1:00-5:00,1:00-5:00,,,,,,2:00-4:00,2:00-4:00,,,
Sarah,,,1:00-5:00,,,,,,,,2:00-4:00,2:00-4:00,2:00-4:00,,
```

I'd like to write a script in R that counts the clusters. If three real sequential values are in the row, then I would like to count them as "one" cluster. If any there is anything less than a cluster of three (i.e. one or two sequential values), then I'd like to count that as "one" separate cluster.

Desired output in csv format:

```
Robert,2,0
John,0,1
Casey,1,1
Sarah,1,1
```

**Edit from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405159/count-clustered-values-in-csv/56448556#comment47040257_29405159):**
The csv the code imports does have a header, but I'd like the code to ignore the header and read from the first line (i.e. Robert,,,1:00-5:00,...). I'd also like to ignore the last column of the imported csv file, which contains the total hours each person worked. Here is a github with a link to an example csv: [timeclock_report.csv](https://github.com/agrobins/r_IslandCount)

```
Employee,"Mar 23, 2015","Mar 24, 2015","Mar 25, 2015","Mar 26, 2015","Mar 27, 2015","Mar 28, 2015","Mar 29, 2015",total hours
"John Smith",16:35 - 21:17 / 4.7,16:35 - 21:17 / 4.7,16:35 - 21:17 / 4.7,,,,11:17 - 16:08 / 4.85,18.9569
"Emily Smith",,,,,,08:13 - 12:40 / 4.45,,4.4472222222222
"Robert Jenkins",16:54 - 21:11 / 4.29,16:54 - 21:11 / 4.29,,,16:22 - 22:59 / 6.61,,,15.18638
"Rachel Lipscomb",,,,,,13:18 - 19:04 / 5.76,,5.7638888888889
"Donald Driver",,,,,08:13 - 13:05 / 4.86,08:13 - 13:05 / 4.86,10:02 - 16:02 / 6,15.14694
```

Comment: have some data to share? 
Briefly you dould do this with reshape2 library `df <-read.csv(file)`, melt(df, id.var="name")` where name or whatever you call the column that has the ids

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. The csv the code imports does have a header, but I'd like the code to ignore the header and read from the first line (i.e. Robert,,,1:00-5:00,...). I'd also like to ignore the last column of the imported csv file, which contains the total hours each person worked. Please excuse the poor formatting of the file, it's not the easiest to work with. Here is a github with a link to an example csv: https://github.com/agrobins/r_IslandCount (timeclock_report.csv)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible `data.table` solution for this old question which uses

- `fread()` for reading the inputs files,
- `melt()` / `dcast()` for reshaping,
- and the `rleid()` function to identify gaps and islands.

For the dataset posted in the question, this code

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

fread("input.csv", header = FALSE, na.strings = c(""), fill = TRUE) %>% 
  .[, V1 := forcats::fct_inorder(V1)] %>%  # to keep the original order in dcast() below
  melt(id.var = "V1") %>% 
  setorder(V1, variable) %>% 
  .[, cluster.id := rleid(V1, is.na(value))] %>%
  .[!is.na(value), .N, by = .(V1, cluster.id)] %>% 
  dcast(V1 ~ N < 3, length, value.var = "N") %>% 
  fwrite("output.csv", col.names = FALSE)
```

creates the csv file as requested:

> ```
> Robert,2,0
> John,0,1
> Casey,1,1
> Sarah,1,1
> ```

---

[In a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405159/count-clustered-values-in-csv#comment47040257_29405159), the OP has provided a link to another sample dataset hosted on github.

With a few modifications,

```
fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/agrobins/r_IslandCount/test_files/timeclock_report.csv"
      , drop = "total hours", na.strings = c("")) %>% 
  .[, Employee := forcats::fct_inorder(Employee)] %>%  # to keep the original order in dcast() below
  melt(id.var = "Employee") %>% 
  setorder(Employee, variable) %>% 
  .[, cluster.id := rleid(Employee, is.na(value))] %>% 
  .[!is.na(value), .N, .(Employee, cluster.id)] %>% 
  dcast(Employee ~ N < 3, length, value.var = "N")
```

we get

> ```
>           Employee FALSE TRUE
> 1:      John Smith     1    1
> 2:     Emily Smith     0    1
> 3:  Robert Jenkins     0    2
> 4: Rachel Lipscomb     0    1
> 5:   Donald Driver     1    0
> ```

The first numeric column named `FALSE` contains the number of clusters consisting of three and more consecutive entries while the second numeric column named `TRUE` contains the number of clusters consisting of 1 or 2 consecutive entries.

#### Reproducible Data

As links to external websites are fragile, here is a copy of the second dataset retrieved from
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/agrobins/r_IslandCount/test_files/timeclock_report.csv

> ```
> Employee,"Mar 23, 2015","Mar 24, 2015","Mar 25, 2015","Mar 26, 2015","Mar 27, 2015","Mar 28, 2015","Mar 29, 2015",total hours
> "John Smith",16:35 - 21:17 / 4.7,16:35 - 21:17 / 4.7,16:35 - 21:17 / 4.7,,,,11:17 - 16:08 / 4.85,18.9569
> "Emily Smith",,,,,,08:13 - 12:40 / 4.45,,4.4472222222222
> "Robert Jenkins",16:54 - 21:11 / 4.29,16:54 - 21:11 / 4.29,,,16:22 - 22:59 / 6.61,,,15.18638
> "Rachel Lipscomb",,,,,,13:18 - 19:04 / 5.76,,5.7638888888889
> "Donald Driver",,,,,08:13 - 13:05 / 4.86,08:13 - 13:05 / 4.86,10:02 - 16:02 / 6,15.14694
> ```